# How to update or set property of firestore document after .onCreate cloud function trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm currently trying to integrate Stripe with my Firebase's Cloud Firestore db through using Cloud Functions for Firebase. The `onCreate` trigger is happening correctly but I also want it to update or set a specific field called "customer_id" into the right document in my Users collection. I think something is a little off about how I write my function since I'm not the most experienced with javascript.

I've also tried

```
return admin.firestore().ref(`Users/${user.uid}/customer_id`).set(customer.id);
```

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
//const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging')();
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
const currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'USD';

// When a user is created, register them with Stripe
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    return stripe.customers.create({
      email: user.email,
    }).then((customer) => {
        return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user.uid).update({"customer_id": customer.id})
    });
  });
```

Customer gets created with Stripe no problem but the "customter_id" field is not getting updated on the Firestore db.

Print screen of the database:
[image]

Print screen of the error log:
[image]

Comment: Is the stripe call response / customer object valid?

Comment: @chris Yes! The customer object is valid.

Comment: Can you share a print screen of your database (from the Firebase console)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I just added two screenshots of DB and error log

Comment: @AntonioChan Thanks. Are you sure the code in your question is the actual code you have deployed, because the error log shows a problem with `admin.firestore().ref`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec oh my! You were right, I didn't deploy correctly. However, that being said. does the code follow good practice and do you have suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, your code follows best practices, in particular it correctly returns the promises returned by the asynchronous operations. If you want more explanations on this key point, you should watch the 3 official videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, from the print screen of the error log, the code you have deployed does not correspond to the code you are referencing to in your question.

The code in your question looks correct.