# Firebase Firestore - Update Firestore database through Cloud Function after Stripe.CreateCustomer

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to update my database after an OnCreate call is made to create a stripe user however I'm having issues. This should be an easy task but I seem to be missing something.

In my SignUpActivity.java file, I create my fields `userStripeCusId` and `userStripeAcctId` as `null` and then try to update the field values later with my cloud function https call.

I know it fires because It creates a new user in the Stripe Database and I have it logging the newly created Stripe customer ID which is what I'm trying to save in my Firestore Database.

Does anyone have any hints on how to solve this?

I've been looking at this youtube video for reference but haven't had any luck with it. The Youtube video works with Realtime Database instead of what I'm using which is Cloud Firestore.

**SignUpActivity.java**

```
private void registerUser() {

userDocRef.set(userInfo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                            //time stamp block
                            Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a", Locale.US);
                            String userCreatedTimestamp = formatter.format(date);
                            System.out.println("Today : " + userCreatedTimestamp);

                            userDocRef.update(
                                    "firstName", firstName,
                                    "lastName", lastName,
                                    "userEmail", userEmail,
                                    "userName", userName,
                                    "userPhoneNumber", completePhoneNumber,
                                    "userStripeCusId", null, // <--FIELD CREATED HERE!
                                    "userStripeAcctId", null,  // <--FIELD CREATED HERE!
                                    "userCreatedTimestamp", userCreatedTimestamp).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: userinfo was created");
                                }
                            });
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user was created");
                            startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        }
                    })

        createStripeCustomer();

    private void createStripeCustomer() {

        mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("createStripeCustomerHTTPSCall").call(data);

    }
```

**index.js**

```
exports.createStripeCustomerHTTPSCall = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userName}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{

    console.log("Stripe Customer profile for " + context.params.userName + " created."); 
    // ^ returns username correctly

    return stripeToken.customers.create(
        {
            description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
            email: context.params.userName,
        },
        (err, StripeCustomer) => {

            console.log("customer id: " + StripeCustomer.id + " customer email: " + StripeCustomer.email);
            //^ returns correct stripe customer ID and associated email it was created with.

            console.log("Creating Stripe customer failed because: " + err.toString())
            admin.database().ref('Users/{userName}').update({ "userStripeCusId": StripeCustomer.id})
// no action is triggered. Stripe customerID is not saved in my firebase DB       

// ^ @DougStevenson pointed out that using admin.database() is meant for a REALTIME DATABASE  which is not my case.

        }
).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
});
```

--------------------------UPDATE-----------------------

**index.js** has been updated to this.

```
exports.createStripeCustomerHTTPSCall = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userName}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{

    console.log("Stripe Customer profile for " + context.params.userName + " created.");
    console.log("Stripe Customer Email for " + context.params.userEmail + " created.");

    return stripeToken.customers.create(
        {
            description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
            email: context.params.userName,
        },
        (err, StripeCustomer) => {
        // asynchronously called
            console.log("customer id: " + StripeCustomer.id + " customer email: " + StripeCustomer.email);
            // admin.database().ref('Users/{userName}').update({ "userStripeCusId": StripeCustomer.id}) // <-- admin.database() is for REALTIME DATABASE 

            console.log("snapshot.get-userStripeCusId-: " +  snapshot.get("userStripeCusId"));

            // console.log("snapshot.get(Users/{userName}/userStripeCusId): " +  snapshot.get("Users/{userName}/userStripeCusId")); <-- doesnt work
            console.log("snapshot.data(): " + snapshot.data().toString()); // <-- returns object
            console.log("snapshot.data().userName: " + snapshot.data().userName); // <-- returns correct userName 
            console.log("snapshot.data().userEmail: " + snapshot.data().userEmail); // <-- returns correct userEmail
```

I've tried the following but have had no luck with them.

1) `return admin.firestore.ref.update({"userStripeCusId": StripeCustomer.id})`

This doesn't work although it's suggested in this [Firebase video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rERRuBjxJ80) at 8:07

2) `return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(snapshot.data().userEmail).update({"userStripeCusId": StripeCustomer.id});`

Tried this also as show in this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497718/how-to-update-or-set-property-of-firestore-document-after-oncreate-cloud-functi?rq=1)

I've also tried following [this Firestore / Stripe source](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/207d80197711d14c93ff639ff8416c75f984c9e6/stripe/functions/index.js#L92) but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the culprit was the `createStripeCustomerHttpsCall`. I reached out to [stripe help center](https://support.stripe.com/) and they sent me to [their docs](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/207d80197711d14c93ff639ff8416c75f984c9e6/stripe/functions/index.js#L92) which I thought I had similar code to. It turns out I did not.

I adjusted their `createStripeCustomer` to the following block below and it worked for me.

```
// When a user is created, register them with Stripe
exports.createStripeCustomerOG = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {

  const customer = await stripeToken.customers.create({email: user.email});
  return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(user.email).update({userStripeCusId: customer.id});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're writing to Realtime Database instead of Firestore:

```
admin.database().ref('Users/{userName}').update({ "userStripeCusId": StripeCustomer.id})
```

`admin.database()` doesn't give you access to Firestore.  Use `admin.firestore()` instead (and note that it has a completely different API).

Also, you are not dealing with the promise returned from that (incorrect) update, so Cloud Functions doesn't know to wait on it to finish.

Comment: So I thought about creating the same question since I'm still having issues with it but I thought it would be better to just edit this one again. I've made progress and I believe I'm at the tail end of the issue.